# entities.SaveChanges() update error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-update

I try to update some field , but what I get is error:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception
>   for details.

```
  var objProduct = _entities.Products.FirstOrDefault(ff => ff.ProuductId == model.ProductId);
objProduct.Title = titles;
 _entities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: *See the inner exception for details.*

Comment: Could you include the inner exception in your question?

Comment: @khlr thank you , I find it and solved

Comment: It would be helpful if told other's what the was, so that they can possibly benefit from your findings.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if (objProduct != null) 
{
    _entities.Entry(objProduct).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    _entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the inner exception for details , and I find the bug

Comment: this does not help anyone. Describe what was in the InnerException and what the bug was, or delete the question altogether.